# parse string date

Tags: javascript

I have a `span` that contain day, month and abbr. of day:

```
<span>8.06 (Fr) </span>
```

I want to parse it and get string representation of this date in the following format:
8 June 2012. There is no year, just insert current year.

How can I do this?

This is my code:

```
date = $(this).closest("li").find("span").text();
var d = new Date();
date = date + '.' + d.getFullYear();
```

It print the following:  `8.06 (Fr) .2012`
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, also I want to print not 06, but June

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
​$(".date").text(function(i,v){
    var m = v.match(/(\d+)\.(\d+)/);
    if ( m ) {
        var date = new Date( (new Date()).getFullYear(), --m[2], m[1]);
        return date.toDateString();
    }
});​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/CuDdD/

If you wanted the full month name, you would need to provide your own array of months:

```
var m, mo = ['January','February','March',    'April',  'May',     'June',
             'July',   'August',  'September','October','November','December'];

$(".date").text(function(i,v){
    if ( m = v.match(/(\d+)\.(\d+)/) ) {
        return m[1] + " " + mo[ --m[2] ] + " " + (new Date()).getFullYear();
    }
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/CuDdD/2/

Answer (score 0):

This should be more than enough to get you started.

```
var date = '8.06 (Fr) ';
var date_components = date.replace(/\s*\(.*?\)\s*/, '').split('.');

for (var i in date_components) {
  date_components[i] = parseInt(date_components[i], 10);
}

date_components.push((new Date()).getFullYear());

console.log(date_components); // Prints [8, 6, 2012]
```

Comment: How can I change 6 to month name(June) ? Thanks

Comment: @user1260827 - Like this: `["Jan","Feb",...,"Jun",..."Dec"][6-1]`